# Refresh windows in netbeans RCP

Tags: netbeans, rcp

I am creatng an netbeans RCP Application.
But i have one problem when opening the windows.

I have dynamicly data from the database, in different tables.

When i first open the window, the data is correct, but when i open it again, then the data has duplicated.

I even tested it with an buttonaction to change an label name, and when i close and open the window, then the new name will be displayed. How can i get it to work to show only the correct data.

I have tried different methodes to repaint an panel, updateui etc. but nothing changes.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanx in advance!

Comment: put some code to be able to help you.. probably you are not clearing your model. it is nothing to deal with netbeans window

Answer (score 0):

can you send some pieces of code?

If you use "open action" via annotation, then only one instance of the topcomponent will be created.

IF you use new TopComponent direct, then all is on your hand.

May be, you should use swingworker or utilities.attachInitJob

Jirka